# unexpected -> userSelect.on 'valuesChanged' ->

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I ran this code from `challengers.coffee` and I get the error `ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:3:31: unexpected ->`, which I was able to distill down further (see comment at line #3):

```
$(document).ready ->
 userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options')
 userSelect.on 'valuesChanged' -> 
  currentUserId = $('#current-challenge-options').data('current-user-id')
   if(currentUserId == userSelect.val())
    $('#current-user-challenges').show()
    $('#challenged_user_challenges').hide()
   else
    $('#challenged_user_challenges').show()
    $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
```

**dueler/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options", data: {current_user_id: current_user.id } %> will

<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @current_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true, id: "current-user-challenges") %>
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenged_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true, id: "challenged_user_challenges") %>
```

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: Yes @muistooshort. It seemed to be the only way to not get an indentation error too. I used this site to help narrow down the problem: http://www.coffeelint.org/

Comment: Your indentation defines the structure of your CoffeeScript so you have to fix the indentation to match the intended structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma missing before `->`. The code should look like (I also removed parentheses in the `if` statement):

```
$(document).ready ->
  userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options')
  userSelect.on 'valuesChanged', -> 
    currentUserId = $('#current-challenge-options').data('current-user-id')
    if currentUserId == userSelect.val()
      $('#current-user-challenges').show()
      $('#challenged_user_challenges').hide()
    else
      $('#challenged_user_challenges').show()
      $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
```